# Как я могу дать объекту динамическое имя свойства?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Вот собственно объект:

```
let obj={
dependsOn:"x",
//ещё много свойств
//Это свойство должно изменять свое имя в зависимости от значения dependsOn
f_of_????:"x^2"
}
```

На месте вопросов нужно поставить что-то, что будет динамически менять имя свойства f_of. Можно изменить f_of на функцию. Это должно работать, даже если dependsOn будет t,y,u и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы имели в виду что-то подобное?

```js
let obj = {
  __x_value: 'x',
  f_of_x: 'some value',
  get dependsOn() {
    return this.__x_value
  },
  set dependsOn(x) {
    let prev = this['f_of_'+this.__x_value]
    delete this['f_of_'+this.__x_value]
    this.__x_value = x
    this['f_of_'+this.__x_value] = prev
  }
}

console.log(obj.dependsOn, obj.f_of_z, obj.f_of_x)

obj.dependsOn = 'z'

console.log(obj.dependsOn, obj.f_of_z, obj.f_of_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

чтобы сделать диначический ключ, то просто он оборачивается в квадратные скобки, например

```
let number = 5;
let obj = {
    ['dynamic_' + number] : 'hello'
}
```

Comment: в вопросе, судя по всему, не про то речь

Comment: ................м.б.

Comment: Да, мне нужно получить свойство этого же объекта и его значение записать в имя уже другого свойства

Comment: @Какой-тоNoName стало понятно ровно ничего

Comment: Если в объекте ```dependsOn = "x"```, то у свойства должно быть имя ```f_of_x```, если ```dependsOn = "t"``` , то ```f_of_t```

Comment: @Какой-тоNoName считаю, что вы хотите сделать что-то страшное и ужасное... имхо надо вам написать непосредственно задачу, которую решаете, чтобы подсказали нормальное решение. Сейчас это выглядит как [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/191482)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не совсем уверен, что вы правильно поняли задачу, т.к. по моему тут очевидно что имел в виду тс. P.S. почти только что мой ответ отметили галочкой

Comment: @ΝNL993 я понял что он имеет в виду, но считаю это бессмысленной вещью  и что-то делается не то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский согласен, не совсем уверен, что у него за задача, но если делать так как тс хочет, то много мороки получается лишней.